# Open Policy Agent - Improve performance of a grouping comprehension

Tags: open-policy-agent, rego

I have a id and role mapping in below format

```json
{
    "ra": [
      {
        "id": 168,
        "code": "AFAP"
      },
      {
        "id": 180,
        "code": "ABC"
      },
      {
        "id": 180,
        "code": "ABCMND"
      }
   ]
}
```

I need the output to be like below

```json
{
    "roleactions": {
        "168": [
            "AFAP"
        ],
        "180": [
            "ABC",
            "ABCMND",
            "DCRMP"
        ]
    }
}
```

So i wrote the below code

```
roleactions = r_map {
    r := data.ra
    r_map := {id: list |
        some i
        id := r[i].id
        list := [obj |
            some j
            r[j].id == id
            obj := r[j].code
        ]
    }
}
```

But when I run this for it almost takes 5-6 seconds

[image: Performance]

Found 1 result in 5682526.465 µs.

Can someone guide on how to make write this policy map to improve performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OPA can evaluate comprehensions like this in linear-time: https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/policy-performance/#comprehension-indexing. The problem in this case is that the local variable `r` is not safe when considering the comprehensions in isolation.

If you refactor the comprehension like below, the runtime should be linear:

```
roleactions := r_map {
    r_map := {id: list |
        some i
        id := data.ra[i].id
        list := [obj |
            some j
            data.ra[j].id == id
            obj := data.ra[j].code
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this does make the difference and makes it fast to 23ms. But the reason i had done it with ra variable is that because in actual it is a very long object. It is more like `data.response.body.ABC["<long string>"]["<long string>"]`, so it becomes quite ugly to repeat the whole object. Whats the best way to go about it?

Comment: If the path through `data` is actually static, then you could just create an alias with an import:

`import data.response.body.ABC["<long string>"]["<long string>"] as x` then refer to `x` inside your rule. The optimizations should still kick in.

Comment: Cool, I will use that